# HTML JQuery slide show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi i  have been trying to do a slide show using HTML and jquery. I tried to figure out why it it not working but could not find out why? That is the reason ia m writing here. I am also trying to get  navigation left and right arrows.

thank you for any help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Roohi Health Screnning</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="roohiSTYLE.css">
        <!--------- SCRIPT FOR SLIDER--------->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.slides.min.js"></script>


         <script>
    $(function(){
      $("#slides").slidesjs({
        width: 940,
        height: 528
      });
    });
  </script>
        </head>
        <body>



    <div id="wrapper">
        <header>

        </header>
        <section>
        <!-- Content Starts Here -->
        <header>
            <h1> Welcome to Roohi</h1> 
        </header>

        <!-- Navigation bar-->  
        <nav id="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="product.html">Products</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="Waterless-Shampo.html">Waterless Shampoo</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Alcohol-Free.html">Alcohol-Free Soap</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Needle.html">Needle</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li><a href="About-us.html">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="Service.html">Service</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="Blood-presureTest.html">BloodPresure</a></li>
                        <li><a href="test2.html">Test2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Test3.html">test3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li><a href="findus.html">FindUs</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
         <div class="logo">

         <a href="index.html"></a>
         </div>


            <div id="slides">
            <ul>

            <li><img src="images/green-stripes.jpg"/></li>  

                <li><img src="images/blue-stripes.jpg"/></li>
                <li><img src="images/pink-stripes.jpg"/></li>
            </ul>
            </div>


        <!-- Content Ends Here -->
        </section>
        <footer>

        </footer>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>


css 



#navigation{
    font-family: crusoe;
    color:#99;
    margin: -0px auto;
    position: realtive;}

#navigation ul{
    list-style-type: none; /*removes bullet points*/
    min-width:200px;}

#navigation ul li {
    display:inline-block;}

#navigation ul li :hover{
background-color: #333}

#navigation  ul li a, visited {
     padding:20px;
     display:inline-block;
     text-decoration:none;
     color:#999;}

     #navigation ul li:hover ul{
     display:block;
      }

#navigation ul ul {
display: none;
position:absolute;}

#navigation ul ul  li{
display: block;}

#navigation ul ul li a:hover {
     display:block;
     position: relative;
     }

#navigation li:nth-child(3) {
padding-right: 80px;}

#navigation li:nth-child(4) {
padding-left: 80px;}


.logo {
background: url(images/Roohi-logo1.png) 50% 0 no-repeat;
background-size: 100px 90px;
width: 100px;
height: 90px;
position: absolute;
top: 30px;
left: 360px;
}

footer
{
    display: table-row;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? What were you expecting it to do, and what is it doing instead?

Comment: the slide it show all the images but not in a slide show and also i want the use to navigate through the website with arrows

Answer (score 0):

Have a close look at their example on http://www.slidesjs.com/ . Pay close attention to their sample markup for the images. They are images inside a div, not images inside li's inside a ul inside a div as you have.

Also, you pasted a bunch of CSS in your question, assuming they are in a proper style block in your real site?

As for the arrow links, they provide you previous and next links which you can style to look like arrows.